# How to make cache for specific url by programmatically?

Tags: full-page-cache, programmatically, magento2.3.4

I need suggestion. I do not have an Idea to set cache for specific page url.
For example
I have an Url : `http://127.0.0.1/magento234/women/tops-women/jackets-women.html`

How can I set full page cache for above page programmtically ?
I do not have any idea how to do it and which observer which classes should be used for that ?
If someone post a code to set cache for specific url ,it would be great help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full page cache in Magento 2 works with Varnish (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html)

You do not need to cache urls programmatically, it will happen as soon as you hit the caching proxy (assuming you configured Magento to use Varnish).

If you want to create the cache before a user hits the page, you could visit the page manually, or write a crawler that loads the page and therefore stores it into cache.

**use command**

```
curl -s -o /dev/null  http://127.0.0.1/magento234/women/tops-women/jackets-women.html
```

Comment: how can I do that by crawler ?

Comment: I think you could start with a curl command doing something like `curl -s -o /dev/null  http://127.0.0.1/magento234/women/tops-women/jackets-women.html` then if that works, call that curl command in a scheduled command like a cron job.

The `-s` operator ensures the command is "silent": do not show progress bars etc.
The `-o` operator ensures the output goes to specified "file" (in this case to /dev/null). Omit this if you want to see the actual output.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to check the output headers received from Varnish. The first time you load a page, the header should show "MISS for the header `X-Cache`. The second time you visit that page, it _should_ show "HIT". If this does not work, Varnish/Magento configuration might not be working correctly.

Comment: Thanks  for your help